# Integrating wordpress and laravel login

Tags: wordpress, laravel, api

I am developing three area for my website.. using WordPress (Front Page), XenForo (Forum), and Laravel (Member Area) ... i already succeed integrating my laravel and XenForo, so when XenForo user login to Member Area my function will check if the user already exist (If XenForo user exist then laravel will create the user in database using XenForo user data, if not exist then login failed)

Now i want to do the same for WordPress .. when user login to member area the function will check if WordPress user is exist or not .. if exist then new user will be created using wordpress user data (name, email, password, and token if possible) if not exist then login failed, but how do i do this? unlike XenForo .. i can't find WordPress API documentation for getting user data

Edit 1 :

This is my login function

```
public function login_post(Request $request){
    // XENFORO API AUTH START 
    $http = Http::withHeaders([
        'XF-Api-Key' => 'SECRET'
    ])->asForm()->post('http://forum.mywebsite.com/api/auth', [
        'login' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);


    if(isset($http['errors'])){
        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Username and Password Error');
    }

    $name = $http['user']['username'];
    $email = $http['user']['email'];
    $password =  $request->password;
    $is_admin =  $http['user']['is_admin'];
    $user_id =  $http['user']['user_id'];

    // XENFORO API AUTH END

    // WordPress API AUTH START
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com/',
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', "Accept" => "application/json", 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'ADMIN' . ':' . 'PASSWORD' ),],
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('users/', [
        'query' => [
            'email' => $request->email,
        ]
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody());

    // WordPress API AUTH END

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        # code...

        if(Auth::user()->role == 0){

            return redirect('dashboard');

        } 

        return redirect('login');

    } else {


        $newUser                    = new User;
        $newUser->name              = $name ;
        $newUser->email             = $email;
        $newUser->password          = bcrypt($password);
        $newUser->role              = $is_admin;
        $newUser->save();

        auth()->login($newUser, true);

        return redirect('dashboard');

    }
}
```

Edit 2 :

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/',
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', "Accept" => "application/json", 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'ADMIN' . ':' . 'PASSWORD' ),],
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('users/', [
        'query' => [
            'email' => $request->email,
        ]
    ]);

    $response = json_decode($response->getBody());

    $name = $response['username'];
    $email = $response['email'];
    $password =  $request->password;
    $is_admin =  $response['role'];
    $user_id =  $response['id'];
```

The Response :

```
array:3 [▼
0 => {#287 ▼
 +"id": 1
 +"name": "Admin"
 +"url": "http://www.mywebsite.com"
 +"description": ""
 +"link": "http://mywebsite.com/author/admin/"
 +"slug": "admin"
 +"avatar_urls": {#285 ▶}
 +"meta": []
 +"_links": {#281 ▶}
}
1 => {#274 ▼
 +"id": 2
 +"name": "Prima"
 +"url": ""
 +"description": ""
 +"link": "http://mywebsite.com/author/prima/"
 +"slug": "prima"
 +"avatar_urls": {#272 ▶}
 +"meta": []
 +"_links": {#279 ▶}
}
2 => {#288 ▼
 +"id": 3
 +"name": "TEST ER"
 +"url": ""
 +"description": ""
 +"link": "http://mywebsite.com/author/testing/"
 +"slug": "testing"
 +"avatar_urls": {#289 ▶}
 +"meta": []
 +"_links": {#291 ▶}
 }
]
```

Comment: Like this : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/ ?

Comment: Thanks @VincentDecaux! i will try it first

Comment: Yes that documentation is correct ... but how do i get the API key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't provide API to check user exists or not, however you can check this by using [List Users](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#list-users) API.

Here is what I have done in Laravel:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', "Accept" => "application/json"],
]);

$response = $client->get('users/', [
    'query' => [
        'search' => 'example@email.com',
    ]
]);

return json_decode($response->getBody());
```

**With Authorization:**

Install this https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth plugin and update headers, `$username` & `$password` refers to WP admin credentials.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', "Accept" => "application/json", 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),],
]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if i said it wrong .. but what i mean is the laravel side will be the one who check will check if user exist or not so when calling WordPress API .. if it's return true (which mean user is exist) then laravel will create new user ,,, if it's return false then login failed .. BTW how do i get my wordpress website API key?

Comment: Put this code in Laravel application in login method. however you can authorize WP user by installing this plugin on WordPress https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth

Comment: update this line - 'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', "Accept" => "application/json", 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),],

Comment: What I understand, while login to Member Area (Laravel), you want to check, if user exists on WordPress end having same email. If user exists on WordPress DB, same user will be created on Laravel DB? right?

Comment: You need to install the plugin on WordPress & put that code in Laravel application

Comment: Thanks @Kaleem, i will try it

Comment: Hello @kaleem, i updated my question ... how do i retrieve WordPress user data? (username, email, etc)

Comment: check what you have in ```$response``` use ```$response =  json_decode($response->getBody());``` instead of returning ```return json_decode($response->getBody());```

Comment: I got this error `Client error: 'GET http:/mywebsite.com/users/?email=test%40testing.com&password=test123' resulted in a '404 Not Found' response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US" class="no-js no-svg"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="wi (truncated...)`

Did i do something wrong? ... the question have been edited

Comment: URL must include api prefix```https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users``` replace this ```'base_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com/'``` with ```'base_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2'```

Comment: Thanks @kaleem it's working now ... but when i tried to get 'username' i get `Undefined index: username` How do i retrieve the username? thanks

Comment: can you post the ```$response``` here?

Comment: seems that list API is not returning all fields related to user, please try to retrieve user by id you getting in response, so basically there will be two api calls one for getting all users and 2nd to get complete data for specific user. use this for 2nd call ```https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>```

Comment: Oh i also tried this `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1` and the `$response` result still like above not returning all field for user with id=1

Comment: Is this plugin only work with HTTPS or it will also work if im using HTTP?

Comment: I already tried the your explanation and the document, but the field that got called is still the same as above (not all of it)